# Set ActiveClass via style isolation

Tags: css, blazor

Imagine the following `NavigationMenuItem` component:

```
@inherits NavLink

<div>
    <NavLink ActiveClass="navigationmenuitem-active" @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes">
        @ChildContent
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

I want to be able to set the `ActiveClass` attribute of the `NavLink` via style isolation.

Is this somehow possible?

I got the style to work when defining the class for the `ActiveClass` globally but I don't really like having global styles.

I found a workaround by not using the `ActiveClass` attribute and instead going with `::deep a.active` in the isolated css file. But this feels wrong.

So is there a way where I can use `ActiveClass` the way I intend it to?

Comment: By Isolation I'm assuming you mean Blazor component CSS.  I set the active class on the out-of-the-box NavMenu elements as follows `ActiveClass="nav-link-active"` and then added to the component css class `::deep .nav-link-active { background-color:blueviolet;}`  It worked - lurid purple when active.  I'm assuming you understand `::deep`.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis that works like a charm. I feel stupid for not thinking about applying `::deep` on the class itself. It makes so much sense! If you'd provide your comment as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: NP, glad to help. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Blazor Isolation CSS on the component.  Set:

```
<NavLink ActiveClass="nav-link-active" .....>
```

Then this in the component CSS for the menu component :

```
::deep .nav-link-active { background-color:blueviolet;}
```

This makes the active link lurid purple.

`::deep` tells Blazor component rendering to apply the style down the tree to all child components.  `<NavLink>` is a child-component and not part of the menu component HTML. See [MS Docs information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information.